# CodeIgniter prevent display of controller/method in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am using CodeIgniter and I have a route set up as follows:

```
$route["(:num)"] ="login/login_by_id/$1";
```

This basically means that when the URL looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/12345
```

This will effectively pass the value 12345 into the `login_by_id` method of the `login` controller.  Everything works fine when I enter the URL directly.  Where I am having a problem is when I try to load a view.  These are the lines which call the view:

```
$data['content'] = 'login_view';
$data['title']   = 'Login';
$data['error_msg'] = 'Invalid password.  Please try again.';
$this->load->view('login_template', $data);
```

My problem is that instead of returning the user back to here:

```
http://mydomain.com/12345
```

The browser directs the user to this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/login/login_by_id
```

How can I change the code so that I return my user back to the same URL they were at previously?  I don't want to be showing the controller/method in the URL address.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to redirect the user back to the login form when he entered wrong password. Am i right.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: check my answer that is entirely based on codeIgniter form class.

Comment: yes, thank you, but your answer includes a reference to admin_model and set_form_validation which I do not have.

Comment: common are you new to codeIgntier that is my model name. You just need to add your model name. you can remove that set_form_validation line. That is for form validation by using form validation class in codeIgntier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function ( the one which you are calling after hitting the submit button) in controller.

```
public function post_login()

  {

      $error_in_validation=set_form_validation($this->config->item('login_form'));

        if($error_in_validation){
            show_form_validation_error('controller_name/login');
        }
        else
        {
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $passwd=$this->input->post('passwd');
            $ret=$this->admin_model->user_login($email, $passwd);

            if($ret == NULL){

                $model=array();
                $model['error_msg']=$this->config->item('login_form_error_code_1');;
                $this->load->view('login',$model);              
            }
            else{
                redirect("home");
            }

        }

    }
```